# Passing multiple values with hidden input fields

Tags: html, input, hidden-field

With a select tag, it is possible to post multiple values using only HTML by selecting more than one option?

For example:

```
<select multiple="" >
    <option value="1"/>
    <option value="2"/>
    <option value="3"/>
</select>
```

Is it possible to pass more than one value as one would achieve with the previous example using one or more `<input type="hidden">` fields? Again, strictly with HTML.

Answer (score 67):

Use [ ] in the field name to send multiple values:

```
<input type="hidden" name="your_field_name[]" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="your_field_name[]" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="your_field_name[]" value="3" />
```

You will get an array of values in the your_field_name field.