# How use ng-repeat for plain text AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I know that something like that, will work:

```
<span ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</span>
```

How can I do the same with plain text?

I would like to append `{{items[0].name}}, {{items[1].name}}, {{items[2].name}}` to my html in plain text :)

In my case, inside an input: `<input type="hidden" name="items" value="{{items[0].name}},{{items[1].name}},{{items[2].name}}"/>`

Thanks guys!

Comment: I don't think you can pass multiple values at once in a hidden field : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073001/passing-multiple-values-with-hidden-input-fields

Comment: It's an unique value, spilted by comas :)

Comment: If you need to know the "key" passed when you are fetching values through ng-repeat, keep the original statement, and try {{$index}}.

Comment: "unique value, spilted by comas" -> Not very elegant... What are you trying to achieve? Pass x values according to user's selection?

Comment: for `input` just use `ng-model` , to append can use `split()` to create array which can run through `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would either use a simple controller function:

```
<input name="items" value="{{commas(items)}}">

//in your controller.js
$scope.commas = function commas(items) {
    return items.join(",");
}
```

Another option might be a filter:

```
<input name="items" value="{{ items | commas }}">

//in your javascript
myApp.filter("commas", function () {
  return function commasFilter(list) {
    return list.join(",");
  }
});
```

But in  general keep the logic in your templates straightforward and move to controllers, filters, or directives when the built-in ones are not sufficient.

Comment: Both solutions are cool. But should I take it that there is no other way such as using the `ng-repeat` directive without HTML tags ?